# Quitar el espacio que sobresale de un borde inferior o superior de una celda en una tabla de HTML

Tags: html, css, html5, html-tabla

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma para eliminar el espacio que sobresale de una al colocar un `border-bottom` o `border-top` en un `td`

Ejemplo:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom: 3px solid black;">Data 1</td>
        <td style="border-bottom: 3px solid black;"> Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

El espacio que quiero remover es el que sobresale de en medio de las dos columnas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar `border-collapse: collapse;` en tu tabla

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom: 3px solid black;">Data 1</td>
        <td style="border-bottom: 3px solid black;"> Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias, estaba agregando el border-collapse al td y no a la tabla

Comment: @Emmanuel, si te sirvió no olvides aceptar la respuesta, eso ayudará a otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas